# How do I modify the tool options palette in Photoshop CC to show possible selections of tools?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

If someone could tell me how to change the tool palette, per the issue below, I'd be grateful.

I'd like to use the pen tool, and specify the attributes of the pen tool by choosing items in the "tools options palette," but the options I see in Photoshop CC are very different from what I see in this online tutorial (text based): http://pshero.com/photoshop-tutorials/graphic-design/wrapping-text-around-an-object

I believe that tutorial might be showing an older version of Photoshop (but the authors don't identify the version). Maybe the tool options palette shown there no longer exists. I'm posting a photo of the palette I'd like to see, and the palette I actually have.

Thank you.

[image: Two versions of tool panel options]

Comment: This is a version conflict indeed. I have no clue how to change the toolbox, but the 'shape' dropdown you have corresponds to the first three icons. The icon you highlighted is the 'path' option.

Comment: @Vincent could you not post answers as comments please ;)

Comment: @Cai I know, right? But I don't think this actually answers the question

Comment: @Vincent well, I think it does... Metis' answer goes a bit further though so I'll let you off

Answer (score 3):

Your "want to see" screen shot is from an **older version** of Photoshop. In order to make room for the Fill and Stroke options, showing the shape options and shape tools in the Control bar was removed. This is actually a step *forward* though....

Older versions of Photoshop had "tear away" tools. This is no longer present in Photoshop CC2017 either....

It *is* still present in **Illustrator** CC2017.

You would click the little arrow on the pop up tools to open them as a separate panel....

[image]

**Photoshop CC** has the ability to reorder and change the tool bar with a different feature now... `Edit > Toolbar`

You can then drag tools up and down or create separate areas on the Toolbar by altering the left pane of the window.

[image]

You can also save and load "sets" of tools for the toolbar. Changes on the left are reflected in the toolbar. Anything in the *right* pane of the window will *not* be present in the toolbar.

So, using the new edit Toolbar feature you can configure the primary tool bar to show all the shape tools if you want. You won't be able to change the shape options from the current Dropdown menu to a click menu though.

Comment: Vincent: Wow, I'm impressed about how thorough your response is. And it does answer my question. It ends a lot of frustration--me trying to figure out how to get some set of options that no longer exist in Photoshop (but I'm sure the same technique that I wanted to use is available by using the tools in a different way than was shown in the tutorial). Thank you, Vincent. Now I think I have to figure out how to record the post as answered.

Comment: My apologies. Metis, that was you that drilled into it so deeply. Many, many thanks.